# Is there an Android widget that shows local humidity and nothing else?

Tags: android, widget

I've been trying to find an Android widget, preferably 1x1, that shows the local humidity. I don't want temperature, wind speed, or any other information... I just want to be able to see the humidity at a glance. I've done a bit of searching in the store, but have only been able to find weather apps, most of which show humidity as an after thought at best.

I'd prefer that app working Network-based by location (not sensor-based on-device) and to be free. Sensor based would require taking my phone outside for a few minutes to get a reading at which point I could just google it... I'd like to be able to see at a glance.

Comment: Maybe [DS Hygrometer - Humidity Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.discipleskies.android.dshygrometer) can kind of work. It does show humidity levels based on location but it does not have a widget.